# Coloring lines as a function of coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, color

I want to colorize lines as a function of coordinates in 3D. Here is my code. In this graphic I used one color. My aim is using a color function based on 3d coordinates.

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 20}, {100, 3}]
graph = Graphics3D[{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[points]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) to color a line segment by blending the two colors associated with the two vertices:

```
SeedRandom[1]
points = RandomReal[{0, 20}, {100, 3}];

Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[points, VertexColors -> (Hue @@@ Rescale[points])]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) + [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) with a color function that depends on the first 3 arguments:

```
ParametricPlot3D[BSplineFunction[points, SplineDegree -> 1][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#, #2, #3] &), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mustafa, you're welcome. And welcome to mma.se. Thank you for the accept.